# How to install pygst under Debian Stretch while the package python-gst-1.0 does not?

Tags: debian, python, gstreamer

I assume my question is valid also for previous versions of Debian, but not sure. Every web [research](http://dese1111.blogspot.fr/2017/01/how-to-install-python-gst-pygst-in.html) tells that to install pygst, the package `python-gst-1.0` should be installed, but the [Debian package content](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/python-gst-1.0/filelist) shows instead :

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gst.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GstPbutils.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/_gi_gst.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Which is conform to what shows `dpkg -L python-gst-1.0` after having installed this package. Of course, I have also :

```
python -c "import pygst"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pygst
```

Which shows it cannot be imported, so probably not installed.

I have not virtualenv installed. `locate pygst.py` returns nothing. I have also installed `gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44878374/python-no-module-named-pygst), but nothing more and `dpkg - L` shows it is not here too.

So what am I missing please ?

Comment: `python-gst-1.0` exists in Ubuntu 16.04.  What does `apt-cache search python gst` return?

Comment: `python-gst-1.0 - GStreamer GObject Introspection overrides for Python
python-gst-1.0-dbg - GStreamer GObject Introspection overrides for Python (debug extensions)
python3-gst-1.0 - GStreamer GObject Introspection overrides for Python (Python 3)
python3-gst-1.0-dbg - GStreamer GObject Introspection overrides for Python (Python 3, debug extensions)
`